# Change the width of the an R terminal

Tags: r, linux, terminal

I would like to change the width of my R terminal dynamically. My situation is:

1. A Linux terminal (not RStudio!)
2. I know about `options("width")`. This works at startup (i.e. in your .Rprofile). But if you change it during an R session, this doesn't do anything.

Comment: If I understand correctly: you are using R (not the IDE) in a terminal/shell, and you want to change how wide R thinks the terminal is? I just tested in a wide terminal, and verified R starts with `getOption("width")` of 80, and `cbind(mtcars,mtcars)[1,]` wraps the columns as it should; then `options(width=160);cbind(mtcars,mtcars)[1,]` does not wrap.

Comment: Yes. So ideally I would like to use `options(width = XX)` from within an R session.

Comment: So you're saying that with the second command, the `cbind(.)` still wraps when it should not?

Comment: Yep. Running `options(width = 10)` doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: On mine, `Sys.getenv("TERM")` returns `"xterm-256color"`. I've tested using `TERM=vt100 R` as well, it still works. I wonder if it's a terminal type that R does not recognize.

Comment: You're right. I'm after line wrapping I suppose. If you hold you the number `1`, at want point does a new line happen

Comment: I'm using line-wrapping as an indication of whether R recognizes and correctly deals with screen width. To be honest, though, R doesn't know or care how big the text screen is, it just tries to be accommodating by wrapping wide-looking textual responses at a certain point. That logic doesn't apply to all things, mostly `print.default` for vectors, frames, and `str`. I don't know what you mean by *"the number `1`"*, but ... with `width=80`, the `cbind(.)[1,]` shows 15 columns. I get additional columns not-wrapped at widths 81, 86, 92, 95, 98, 103, and finally 108.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, if you typed: `x = 1111111111 ..... 111111`

Comment: I can type `1`s all the way across, regardless of `options("width")`. If you cannot, then that has nothing to do with R, that's your terminal emulator (or console).